# Feed a video file to v4l2sink using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2, v4l2loopback

I would like to feed a video file to my virtual video device using gstreamer and v4l2loopback.

Using `videotestsrc`, something like this works (i.e. I can open my virtual device from VLC):

```
gst-launch -v videotestsrc ! queue ! decodebin2 name=dec ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

However, the exact same code does not work with my video file:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=~/Documents/my_video.ogv ! queue ! decodebin2 name=dec ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

It actually gets stuck in the "PREROLLING" phase:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
```

Can anybody see why? Do I miss some conversion between `filesrc` and `decodebin2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why exactly, but I was missing the `! videoscale !` step. And the `! queue !`'s are apparently not necessary.

Here is the working line:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=~/Documents/my_video.ogv ! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

Comment: Your command leads to `ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0: Device '/dev/video0' is not a output device.` on my machine. Why is it so? I am trying to redirect a video to `/dev/video0`

Comment: For 1.0, `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="test.mkv" ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0`.